# Azure Function App: Function level concurrency settings

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics

Is there any chance to have  concurrency host options at individual function level not at Function App level.
For example, My one function is ok to take multiple messages from service bus topic but one requires to process one message at a time.
Right now I'm facing issue because of concurrency, so I've changed it to one, but disadvantage is my other functions listening on service bus are serialized .

If concurrency options are not possible on individual function level, than what is the reason behind it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Singleton] attribute - this is like a distributed lock around small sections of code. But this is only available in C# attribute (not function.json) so you need to do this from Visual Studio tooling (not csx). See https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Singleton

Comment: That is only for webjobs not for serverless functions. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/912, people are waiting for this. But issue is still open on git.

Comment: Functions is a layer on top of WebJobs; so many webjob features are also available in Functions. In this case, there's not a Function.json representation for Singleton, but you can access it directly via the attributes when using Visual Studio tooling.